# While loop replacing Else Statement?(Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Ok here it is

```
  done = False
  while not done:
      quit = input ("Do you want to quit? ")
      if quit == "y" :
         done = True;

      if not done:
       attack = input ("Does your elf attack the dragon? ")
       if attack == "y":
          print ("Bad choice, you died.")
          done = True;
```

but when I get to

```
           Do you want to quit?
```

And I enter

```
       n
```

I get

```
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "C:\Users\your pc\Desktop\JQuery\dragon.py", line 4, in <module>
           quit = input ("Do you want to quit? ")
         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

according to this  http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=2Z2pH0Ls9Ew#!
it should work

Comment: Try `raw_input()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` behaves differently in version 2 and 3 of Python. You're clearly on Python 2, because it tries to interpret the input in the Python environment.

You will want `raw_input()` instead, which simply reads in a string.

Edit:
To make the difference clear, in Python 2:

```
>>> type(input())
0
<type 'int'>
>>> type(raw_input())
0
<type 'str'>
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> type(input())
0
<class 'str'>
```